# Is it possible to show div's parent without any id

Tags: jquery

i have a div and div has a span

what i want is that when hover div's span will be visible.

Can i do that without the need out div's id ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely. Just use `$('span').parent()`.

Comment: yeap but i have for example 8 div so 8 parent span this will visible all of them ?

Comment: I honestly did not understand that. Can you elaborate or provide more details in your question?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming I've understood your question correctly, this should work:

```
$("div").hover(
    function() { $("> span", this).show(); },
    function() { $("> span", this).hide(); }
);
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/9Y6ZR/)

Comment: thank you.I think this is the better way instead of getting id's

Comment: maybe it's strange but this works on Firefox but not on Chrome

Answer (score 0):

```
$("div").hover(function(e) {
  $(e.target).find("span").show();
}, function(e) {
  $(e.target).find("span").hide();
});
```

Comment: Isn't toggle a better approach?

Answer (score 0):

A wild stab, as I'm not sure I understand your question.

```
$('span').on('hover', function(){
  $(this).parent('div').show();
});
```

`$(this)` is a reference to the `<span>` currently hovered. I then travel up the DOM (`.parent`) and show the parent `<div>`. Simple.